# Subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout cause blank cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Using  `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` ,i have 2 columns- collection view that works great .
Problem have started when i needed a constant distance between cells at the same row, when they have a dynamic height .

So , i have subclass  UICollectionViewFlowLayout as everybody do, but what it did, is to eliminate the next cells to be loaded to screen, so while scrolling i have blank spaces ,without cells, and than they are suddenly loaded in late . looks like

```
 1 2
 3 4
   6
   8
   10
```

Than,  5-7-10 suddenly appears late. seems that the subclass change the delegate method that creates the cells, and its now not being called at time, to load the next cells .

Whats wrong with it ? i am struggling 3 days with no results.
The subclass method that suppose to make the spacing equal(and cause the problem)

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* currentItemAttributes = [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      if (indexPath.item < numColumns)
    {
        CGRect f = currentItemAttributes.frame;
        f.origin.y = 0;
        currentItemAttributes.frame = f;
        return currentItemAttributes;
    }


    NSIndexPath* ipPrev = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexPath.item-numColumns inSection:indexPath.section];
    CGRect fPrev = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:ipPrev].frame;
    CGFloat YPointNew = fPrev.origin.y + fPrev.size.height + 10;
    CGRect f = currentItemAttributes.frame;
    f.origin.y = YPointNew;
    currentItemAttributes.frame = f;
    return currentItemAttributes;
}
```

**EDIT !**

After 3 days ,i have manage to change something that solve the problem, but makes no sense.
**I have changed the content height of the collection view to be 6 times the screen size**! this solved the problem. I think i am doing something wrong with setting the content side of flow and collection:

```
TopAlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[TopAlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    CGRect  size=CGRectMake( ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-collectionWidth)/2,
                            upperView.frame.size.height, collectionWidth, 6.5*([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-upperLineMargin));
    self.GridView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:size collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [self.GridView registerClass:[GridCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Only now, he loads all cells at time. problem is that now i can't get to the end of the collection.

Comment: Everytime I see the blank screen while using `uitableview` or `uicollectionview` it turns out I am forgetting `self.tableview.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad`. So can you check that out?

Comment: if i was forgetting the delegate, i wouldn't see even 1 cell on screen, problem is that the delegate is not being called on time , because it calculates the wrong visible rect when i subclass layout.

Comment: Oops, I thought you see blank screen, hope someone can help maybe you can prepare a sample project of this. It can speed up to get an answer.

Comment: Thats ok , but see my edit, i have discovered something new !

Comment: That just senseless to me; however, if it works, keep it, till a pro answers.

Comment: @Curnelious you should add the fix that solved this issue as an official "answer".